# Is this a true way of using parallel pools in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, parallel-processing

I am working with a machine having 2 physical CPU cores. and the `Arii_Modified` function is written by me. When I run the code as follows without using parallel pools, the time taken is `425.456` seconds

```
profile on
[Ps,Pd,Pv,ThetaMean,Variance,frobonius] = Arii2011_Modified(C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33);
profile off
profsave
span = C11+C22+C33;
total=Pd+Ps+Pv+frobonius;
save('results.mat');
```

But when I start a parallel pool with two workers as follows:

```
parpool('local',2)
profile on
[Ps,Pd,Pv,ThetaMean,Variance,frobonius] = Arii2011_Modified(C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33);
profile off
profsave
span = C11+C22+C33;
total=Pd+Ps+Pv+frobonius;
save('results.mat');
p = gcp;
delete(p)
```

The time taken is 687.687 seconds.
Am I using the parallel pool in a true way?
The code within the function `Arii2011_modified` is completely a sequential one.
I've used MEX solution to accelerate it but no parallel programming code has been used neither in `Arii2011_Modified.m` code nor in C++ source of the mex functions within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parpool` alone doesn't magically make just any code run in parallel and execute faster. It simply creates a pool of MATLAB instances which can serve as workers which can process tasks you pass to them. You simply created a parallel pool (using `parpool`) but never actually use it therefore you can't expect your code to execute any faster. The increased execution time  is simply because of the time required to start the pool.

If you want to actually *use* the parallel pool you created, you'll need to wrap some part of your code within a `parfor` construct where each iteration within the `parfor` is independent and each iteration through the `parfor` loop will be handed off to one of the available workers.

If your code isn't actually parallelizable, it may be worth  taking a closer look at `Arii2011_Modified.m` and seeing if you can perhaps vectorize some parts of it to improve execution times.

The Mathworks has some great [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel-computing-fundamentals.html) on how to take advantage of parallel computing within MATLAB.

As a side note, if you want to actually measure execution times, `profile` is a bad way to do that since that introduces a *lot* of overhead since it's tracking all function calls. Instead you should use [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html).

Comment: thanks. My code isn't in a state to use `parfor`, etc. because I've implemented all of the `for loops` within C++ and they are precompiled. But another option is to use distributed arrays and give each `worker` a part of the whole array to run the function on it. how can I do that programmatically not manually? Is it possible?

Comment: @sepideh There is no single best way to do that. You'd have to implement that yourself. As I said, it may be worth looking at vectorizing some of the code in MATLAB (remove the for loops) and compare execution times.

Comment: ok, I'll show you the code now. there is no way to vectorize the code within matlab anymore.

Comment: @sepideh THat's really beyond the scope of this question and is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com This question was about specifically why `parpool` didn't decrease execution times.