# Why does arrayfun only use a single core?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I try to estimate

```
% matlabpool open 2; % line 1
tic; arrayfun(@(x) sum(sum(rand(1000))), [1 : 100]); toc;
Elapsed time is 4.070030 seconds.
```

When I uncomment the first line so that I create a pool of 2 workers, I get the same time result.

Why some obvious system function don't execute in parallel mode automaticaly?
Has Matlab any similar to arrayfun function for GPU, when we get parallel running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you don't get any speed increase by calling `matlabpool` before calling `arrayfun` is that just the act of creating multiple workers doesn't make *all* code utilize these workers to perform calculations. If you want to exploit the pool of workers, you need to explicitly parallelize your code with [`parfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) (related info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509094/is-this-a-true-way-of-using-parallel-pools-in-matlab/41509139#41509139)).

```
parfor k = 1:10
    result{k} = sum(sum(a*b));
end
```

In general, `arrayfun` does *not* do any parallelization or acceleration. In fact, it's often slower than simply writing out the `for` loop because the explicit `for` loop allows for better JIT acceleration.

```
for k = 1:10
    result(k) = sum(sum(a * b));
end
```

If you want to perform the operation you've shown using the GPU, if the input data to `arrayfun` is a `gpuarray`, then it will excecute on the GPU (using the [distributed version of `arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html)). The issue though is that anything performed on the GPU using `arrayfun` *has* to be element-wise operations only so that the operation on each element is independent of the operations on all other elements (making it parallelizable). In your case, it is *not* element-wise operations and therefore the GPU-version of `arrayfun` cannot be used.

As a side-note, you'll want to use [`parpool`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html) rather than `matlabpool` since the latter has been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. Have I correctly understand that GPU can be really fast only for huge arrays and simple operations (such as .+, .-, .*, ./)? Not all operation from https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html can be fast for gpu?

Comment: @user7484269 No, all of those functions can be accelerated thanks to the GPU, I was referring to `arrayfun` explicitly. Only `arrayfun` can perform element-wise operations. There is non-significant overhead when moving data to the GPU prior to the calculation though.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. And as a maeby last question for this topic: what mean time acceleration did you achieve using gpu while working with Matlab?

Comment: @user7484269 That is completely dependent upon the size of the data and the operation.

Comment: Ok, If I correctly understood,"marked" I checked your answer. But what about your approximate acceleration range for GPU?

Comment: @user7484269 Again, it depends on the data, the problem, the GPU, and a host of other things. Just test it out for yourself and see if it's appropriate for your specific usecase

Answer (score 1):

Core MATLAB does use threads and vector operations, but you have to vectorize the code yourself. For your example, for instance, you need to write

```
A = rand(1000, 1000, 100);
B = sum( sum( A, 1 ), 2 );
```

B is now a 1-by-1-by-100 array of the sums. I've used two sums to help you understand what's going on, if you *actually* wanted to sum every number in a matrix you'd go `sum(A(:))`, or for this batch example, `sum( reshape(A, [], 100) )`.

For task parallelism rather than data parallelism use `parfor`, `batch`, `parfeval` or some other parallel instruction.